# Delta Servo Drive 220V/400V Series

Tags: inverter, servo, vfd, power-grid

ASDA-A2 Delta Servo Drives including two types: 220V and 400V series that it seems the difference is input voltage of the Servo Derive. but i doubt 220VAC or 400VAC is line to line voltage or line to neutral voltage of The local electricity grid? and if it's refers to line to line voltage, is it possible to feed 220VAC Servo Drive with 400 VAC (line to line voltage) with some considerations or not?

Comment: Link to the data sheet please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is connector to connector voltage. It can be line to line if you connect all three phases or it is line to neutral if you connect a single phase (if allowed).

No, you may not use 3ph 400V fo a device that has 220VAC input, only phase + neutral (if single phase is allowed, only low power servo drive). If you intend to connect all three phases 400VAC to your servo drive, then you should use an autotransformer 400/220.

I do think the manual is self explanatory:

[image]